# Allocating and freeing dynamic memory

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, free, fclose

I've written a short program that reads JPEGs from a memory card and writes the JPEGs as individual files as the output. The program works as I intended, but I understand my code is poorly written as a don't free dynamic memory from the heap.

I've attempted to use `fclose()` and `free()` in my code, but I get the following error when I do:

```
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted
```

I've commented out these functions, and my code works as intended.
I want to know why it didn't work when I tried to use these two functions. What did I do wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// define/declare variables
typedef uint8_t BYTE;
FILE *outptr; 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
// declare variables
int counter = 0;

// ensure correct command-line useage
if (argc != 2)
{
    printf("Useage: ./recover memorycard\n");
    return 1;
}

// open memory card to read
FILE *inptr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if (inptr == NULL)                    // ensure enough memory
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file");
    return 2;
}

// read into infile, 512 bytes at a time until end of file
BYTE buffer[512];
while (fread(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, inptr) == 512)
{
    // if JPEG headerfile is found
    if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
    {
        if (counter > 0)             // if not first JPEG
        {
            // close previous file
     //     fclose(outptr);                            // here is the issue
     //     free(outptr);                              // and here
        }

        // allocate memory for new file
        char *outfile = malloc(sizeof(BYTE) * 512);
        if (outfile == NULL)
        {
            printf("Not enough memory for output file\n");
            fclose(inptr);
            return 3;
        }

        // write new file name
        sprintf(outfile, "%03i.jpg", counter);

        // open new file
        outptr = fopen(outfile, "w");
        if (outptr == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file.\n");
            fclose(inptr);
            return 4;
        }

        // write 512 bytes from infile into new file
        fwrite (buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, outptr);

        counter++;

    }

    // if not start of new JPEG
    else if (buffer[0] != 0xff || buffer[1] != 0xd8 || buffer[2] != 0xff || (buffer[3] & 0xf0) != 0xe0)
    {
        // if already found JPEG
        if (counter > 0)
        {
            // keep writing into JPEG
            fwrite (buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, outptr);
        }

        continue;
    }

}
// Close remaining files once gone through memory card
//    fclose(inptr);                        // here
//    free(inptr);                          // and here
}
```

Comment: `char *outfile = malloc(sizeof(BYTE) * 512);` <<-- you are leaking memory inside the loop.

Comment: I tried putting free(outptr) after I write to the file, but I get this error 'Fatal error: glibc detected an invalid stdio handle'

Comment: The commented-out `free(outptr);` would be nonsense if it were active in-code. `outptr` is a `FILE*`, you close it with `fclose` and you're done. the `free` is nonsense. The same is true for `free(inptr)` at the bottom of the source list. And I don't understand the point of dynamic-allocation of the filename either. That `sprintf` will generate at-most about a 30-char filename. dynamic allocation of the filename seems completely overkill and just something else you need not have to manually manage if you use a simple automatic `char outfile[128];` when building the name.

Comment: Ah I see, i've done as you suggested and assigned the filename on the stack before the loop - makes a lot more sense, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first iteration of a loop the `outptr` variable is uninitialized, so any action taken with it brings undefined behavior.
Specifically, you haven't assigned it any value obtained from `fopen()` so you should not `fclose()` it.
Also, you haven't assigned it any value obtained from `malloc()` or `calloc()` so you should not `free()` it.

You need to `fopen()` a file when you need to write to it, keep a pointer to it as long as it's needed (you write to it) and `fclose()` when done. No `malloc()` and no `free()` is necessary for file handling.

Here is the code simplified a bit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// define/declare variables
typedef uint8_t BYTE;
FILE *outptr = NULL; 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // declare variables
    int counter = 0;

    // ensure correct command-line useage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Useage: ./recover memorycard\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // open memory card to read
    FILE *inptr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)                    // ensure enough memory
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file");
        return 2;
    }

    // read into infile, 512 bytes at a time until end of file
    BYTE buffer[512];
    while (fread(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, inptr) == 512)
    {
        // if JPEG headerfile is found
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            if (outptr != NULL)             // previous file is opened
            {
                fclose(outptr);             // close it
            }

            char outfilename[ 512];         // output file name

            sprintf(outfilename, "%03i.jpg", counter ++);

            // open new file
            outptr = fopen(outfilename, "w");
            if (outptr == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file.\n");
                fclose(inptr);
                return 4;
            }
        }

        // whether it's a new or still the same file...
        if(outptr != NULL)
        {
            // keep writing into JPEG
            fwrite (buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, outptr);
        }
    }

    fclose(outptr);         // close the last file created
    fclose(inptr);          // as well as the input
}
```

I have removed a call to `malloc` for a file name - it's short enough to be allocated automatically on the stack, and you do not need to `free` it after use (which you forgot to do, BTW, hence creating a memory leak...)

I noticed that you do exactly the same `write` in `if` and in `else` branch, so I moved it outside the conditional.

I also removed the `continue;` instruction as the loop continues itself once control reaches the closing brace.

And the most important: I added initialization `FILE* outptr = NULL;` so it can be check *on the file pointer* variable whether the file has been successfuly opened instead of checking an apparently unconnected `counter` variable.

Comment: You're completely right, this is where I was confused. I have now initialised outptr to NULL before the loop. Ive also adapted the program so only when the first JPEG is found (and inptr is initialised), do I begin to write into the output file.

And I've also scrapped my calls to malloc(), seeing it is unnecessary. That's something I defo need to work on a bit more. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @RoryV.S. Added my version of code with some description, hopefully it will help you, too. Be aware I have NOT compiled and run it, so be careful when adopting it.

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much! I've worked through and adapted my code accordingly, I'll post below :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// define byte
typedef uint8_t BYTE;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ensure correct command-line useage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Useage: ./recover memorycard\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // open memory card 
    FILE *inptr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)                    
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file");
        return 2;
    }

    // buffer for file names
    char output[8];
    
    // keep track of file number for file names
    int counter = 0; 
    
    // pointer to write JPEGs to
    FILE *outptr = NULL;
    
    // read into infile, 512 bytes at a time until end of file
    BYTE buffer[512];
    while (fread(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, inptr) == 512)
    {
        // New JPEG signatiture found
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            // if not first JPEG, close previous output file
            if (outptr != NULL)
                fclose(outptr);
            
            // write new file name
            sprintf(output, "%03i.jpg", counter);
            
            // open new file
            outptr = fopen(output, "w");
            if (outptr == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file.\n");
                fclose(inptr);
                return 4;
            }
            
            // increment file counter
            counter++;
        }

        // if output file is already open
        if (outptr != NULL)
        {
            // keep writing into JPEG
            fwrite (buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, outptr);
        }
    }
    
    // close final file if still open
    if (outptr != NULL)
        fclose(inptr);
}
```